# Ordering of the CSS stylesheets with bootstrap and kendo-bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, kendo-ui, telerik

I have ASP.NET MVC application and im using Telerik's **UI for ASP.NET MVC** framework for few controls.
1> The application is using [bootstrap 3.3.6](http://getbootstrap.com/)
2> Telerik also provides bootstrap styling for their controls. so i have bundled those styles as well.
3> I also have my own site.css so i can override some of the styles.

Here is my BundleConfig.cs

```
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            // jQuery, bootstrap and kendo JavaScripts are bundled here



            // kendo bootstrap-theme CSS
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo-bootstrap/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.412/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.412/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"));

            // bootstrap CSS
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap/css").Include(
                     "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css"));

            // site CSS
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                     "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
```

This is how im referencing them in layout.cshtml

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


            @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo-bootstrap/css")
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap/css")
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")


            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo/2016.1.412")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Do we need to refer CSS in particular order? Whats the recommended order?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the order in your razor (cshtml) file:

```
// Generic bootstrap css
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap/css")  
// Css that kendo overwrites or extends based on bootstrap
@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo-bootstrap/css")
// Your own css that can override the previous css files
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

that way bootstrap doesn't overwrite the style that was set by the kendo-ui library.